# Always Selecting the Else Statement in Spinner

Tags: android, textview, spinner

I am trying to set the text of textView according to the item selected in the spinner. But it is always showing the value of the else statement. Can someone please help me in solving this.
The code is given below.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] names = {"Shashank","Abhijay"};
        String[] state_array = {"Select City","Bangalore","Jaipur"};
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spinner_state = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner_state.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    state_array ));

        if(spinner_state.equals(state_array[1]))
        {
        TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
        candi_name.setText(names[0]);
        }
        if(spinner_state.equals(state_array[2])){
            TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
            candi_name.setText(names[1]);
        }
        else{
            TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
            candi_name.setText(" ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't compare `Spinner` items with instance of `Spinner`. implement `onItemSelected()` listener for `Spinner` and do it in..

Comment: Spinner object never equals with String object..

Comment: actually what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to onItemSelectedListener() to catch selected spinner item. After spinner initialization add below code and delete if/else statements:

```
spinner_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        if(spinner_state.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(state_array[1]))
        {
            TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
            candi_name.setText(names[0]);
        }
        if(spinner_state.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(state_array[2]))
        {
            TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
            candi_name.setText(names[1]);
        } 
    }


    @Override 
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
                candi_name.setText(" "); }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use onItemSelectedListener

```
spinner_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your spinner if condition with:

```
 // your code above...
if(spinner_state.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(state_array[1]))
    {
    TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
    candi_name.setText(names[0]);
    }
    if(spinner_state.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(state_array[2])){
        TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
        candi_name.setText(names[1]);
    }
    else{
        TextView candi_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CandidateName);
        candi_name.setText(" ");
    }
 //your code below
```

Comment: From your code always first item will set to Textview..you know why after set adapter to the spinner.. it will select first one.op need to write onItemSelectedListener